# Add upload image button in widget

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i want to create a widget used to upload image or select image from media, So user can Select image or choose one, i tried this

**Widget Page**

```
class wd_aboutus extends WP_Widget
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     **/
    public function __construct()
    {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname' => 'wd_aboutus',
            'description' => 'Display About us data with image'
        );

        parent::__construct( 'wd_aboutus', 'WD - About Us', $widget_ops );

        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'upload_scripts'));
        add_action('admin_enqueue_styles', array($this, 'upload_styles'));
    }

    /**
     * Upload the Javascripts for the media uploader
     */
    public function upload_scripts()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
        wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
        wp_enqueue_script('upload_media_widget', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/upload-media.js');
    }

    /**
     * Add the styles for the upload media box
     */
    public function upload_styles()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the HTML for this widget.
     *
     * @param array  An array of standard parameters for widgets in this theme
     * @param array  An array of settings for this widget instance
     * @return void Echoes it's output
     **/
    public function widget( $args, $instance )
    {
        // Add any html to output the image in the $instance array
    }

    /**
     * Deals with the settings when they are saved by the admin. Here is
     * where any validation should be dealt with.
     *
     * @param array  An array of new settings as submitted by the admin
     * @param array  An array of the previous settings
     * @return array The validated and (if necessary) amended settings
     **/
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) 
    {

    }

    /**
     * Displays the form for this widget on the Widgets page of the WP Admin area.
     *
     * @param array  An array of the current settings for this widget
     * @return void
     **/
    public function form( $instance )
    {
        $title = __('Widget Image');
        if(isset($instance['title']))
        {
            $title = $instance['title'];
        }

        $image = '';
        if(isset($instance['image']))
        {
            $image = $instance['image'];
        }
    ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Image:' ); ?></label>
            <input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" class="widefat" type="text" size="36"  value="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" />
            <input class="upload_image_button button button-primary" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
        </p>
    <?php
    }
}
```

this is the widget page i have created and i create a js file Like

**upload-media**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var image_field;
    jQuery(function($){
      $(document).on('click', 'input.upload_image_button', function(evt){
        image_field = $(this).siblings('.img');
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=1');
        return false;
      });
      window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = $('img', html).attr('src');
        image_field.val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
      }
    });
});
```

it work fine, it did show the box to upload or select image that used in wordpress but it show it in the button of the page, and it doesn't appear correctly and cant be used

[image]

i dont know what happen So any one can help ?

By the way if this info is important this is my created theme not a theme by wordpress

**Answer**
Ok i fixed by changing my js file to

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
 function media_upload( button_class) {
    var _custom_media = true,
    _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
    jQuery('body').on('click',button_class, function(e) {
        var button_id ='#'+jQuery(this).attr('id');
        /* console.log(button_id); */
        var self = jQuery(button_id);
        var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
        var button = jQuery(button_id);
        var id = button.attr('id').replace('_button', '');
        _custom_media = true;
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
            if ( _custom_media  ) {
               jQuery('.custom_media_id').val(attachment.id); 
               jQuery('.custom_media_url').val(attachment.url);
               jQuery('.custom_media_image').attr('src',attachment.url).css('display','block');   
            } else {
                return _orig_send_attachment.apply( button_id, [props, attachment] );
            }
        }
        wp.media.editor.open(button);
        return false;
    });
}
media_upload( '.upload_image_button');
});
```

But i still want to get the name of image choosed and but it in my text field :)

So i need your help

Comment: You shouldn't be sending raw queries to the server via jquery, take a look at this: http://www.lenslider.com/articles/wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-tips-on-using-it-within-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

```
            <input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" class="widefat img" type="text" size="36"  value="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" />
```

Please add "img" in to input class...

```
image_field = $(this).siblings('.img');
```

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/